# Memory-usage of Hibernate's cascade=REMOVE

Tags: java, hibernate, memory, model, entity

I have a complex entity model with several mapped collections of the following kind:

```
public class RoleDAO extends AbstractEntity {
    // ...

    public static final String PROPERTY_ROLE = "role";

    @ManyToOne
    private Role role;

    // ...
}

public class Role extends AbstractEntity {
    // ...

    @OptimisticLock(excluded = true)
    @LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.EXTRA)
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = RoleDAO.PROPERTY_ROLE, cascade = { CascadeType.REMOVE })
    private List<RoleDAO> roleDAOs = new ArrayList<RoleDAO>();

    // ...
}
```

There exist approximatly 20 `Role` instances with 20.000 `RoleDOA` instances for each of them. Whenever I try to remove a single Role object using `em.remove(role)` Hibernate needs an enormous amount of memory. Using jProfiler to monitor the removal I found out that Hibernate seems to instanciate much more `RoleDAO` objects than expected - if not all 400.000 of them.

**Is this behaviour normal for Hibernate?**

I've worked around this by removing the cascade and deleting all related `RoleDAO` entries using a named-query before calling `em.remove()` – but that makes the handling much more complex related to the complete model.

*Tested with Hibernate v3.3.1.GA in a JBoss v4.2.3... plan to upgrade to JBoss v7 and current Hibernate in the near future.*

Comment: does it occure if you change it to a normal collection instead of a lazy collection?

Comment: ...worth a try. Will check it tomorrow. But the extra-lazy is very much needed.